# Time limit,how to reduce the code execution time for large numbers to a billion?

Tags: python

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
s = 0
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    g = 0
    while i != 0:
        k = i % 10
        g = g + k
        i = i // 10
    if g % 2 == 0:
        s = s + 1      
print(s)
```

The task itself:Count the number of natural numbers on the segment from a to b, the sum of the digits of which is even.

Comment: You can e. g. work with strings instead of ints. Even digits in the strings don't matter, so you can remove them. Remaining odd digits must only be counted (str length) to know if the whole digit sum is even. Also you only need to inspect numbers with 0 in the last place. The following numbers with 1 to 9 in last place always switch between even and odd (theoretically you could extend this idea to the other places in the number).

Comment: Where is this problem from? Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(end-start)//2` for full blocks of `n*10+[0...9]` inside the range and compute the small rests with your algorithm.

```
def q1(a,b):
    s = 0
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
        g = 0
        c = i
        while i != 0:
            k = i % 10
            g = g + k
            i = i // 10
        if g % 2 == 0:
            s = s + 1      
    return s

def q2(a,b):
    br = b%10
    ar = 10 - a%10
    return q1(a, a+ar-1) + ((b - br) - (a + ar)) // 2 + q1(b-br,b)
```

I tested the implementation with

```
import random
for _ in range(1000):
    a = random.randint(1,1000)
    b = random.randint(100,100000)
    assert q1(a,a+b) == q2(a,a+b), 'not the same result'
```

Benchmark

```
%timeit q1(10,10000)         #=4995 in ~O(n^2)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 7.58 ms per loop
%timeit q2(10,1_000_000_000) #499999995 in ~O(1)
# 100000 loops, best of 5: 7.17 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea here is not to loop through everything.

The sum of digits of every second number is even:

```
101 -> even
102 -> odd
103 -> even
```

So to find the amount of numbers that have an even sum of digits all you have to do is `(start-end)/2`and then account for the edge cases, basically if the number you start and end on have even or odd sums.

Edit: I missed one of the weirdnesses at the 10s. The example beeing 29 and 30 which are both odd. So to amend that, every block of 10 numbers like 30-39 has 5 even and 5 odds. That increases the edge case you need to consider to a couple numbers befor you hit the first multiple of 10 and after you hit your last multiple of 10 - 1.

Comment: Which of 29 and 30 have an even digit sum? Maybe not quite as trivial as you make it sound :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode absolutely right, i extended it a bit. This should (hopefully) work now.

Comment: I implemented your (edited) approach. But without thinking through the different cases. OP already provided a solution for head and tail of the range.